# Ubuntu 20.04 always forces me to create a new user at boot

Tags: 20.04, login, users, gdm

I have newly installed Ubuntu 20.04, customized GDM3, installed my needed software and everything appeared to be successful.  However, when I reboot, Ubuntu asks me to create a new user for some reason. I am unable to bypass this, and must create the user, after which I can log out normally.  The login screen then shows both the new user and the correct original one, which I can log in to and continue.

I searched Ask Ubuntu and found 1 instance of a similar problem.  Unfortunately the solution presented there (reinstall ubuntu-desktop)  did not work for me.

The graphics driver is Nvidia 440.100, if that is relevant.

Can someone suggest a course of action to resolve this?  I'm reluctant to re-install Ubuntu as there is considerable customization.  Aside from this new-user issue, it's working perfectly so far.

[Edit] Oct.1/20
This issue was known in Ubuntu 18 and 19, and appears to be the same as [this bug][1].

I found that while researching for why, at boot, the syslog was showing these lines:

```
Oct  1 15:39:49 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///run/gnome-initial-setup) of the array-update: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
Oct  1 15:39:49 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]: Could not execute sparql: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
Oct  1 15:39:50 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///run/gnome-initial-setup) of the array-update: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
Oct  1 15:39:50 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]: Could not execute sparql: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
Oct  1 15:39:50 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///run/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup-uid) of the array-update: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
Oct  1 15:39:50 mynode tracker-miner-f[1871]: Could not execute sparql: There is not enough space on the file system for update operations
```

The message is misleading, because the partition is only 20% used.

Comment: I guess I should clarify.. Ubuntu is forcing me through a dialogue to create a new user; it's not picking a name itself.

Comment: "*customized GDM3*" | "*there is considerable customization*" | since the behavior you are observing is far from the behavior of a normal Ubuntu installation, it stands to reason that some aspect of your extensive customization is responsible for the undesired behavior.  You should research and list in detail all of your customizations, especially those changes pertaining to GDM.

Comment: So in your home directory are ther now several username folders? One for each user you created?

Comment: The customizations are largely cosmetic, and I have added two extensions:  clock override to get a custom datetime format, and workspace matrix to restore the 2x2 format.

Comment: I have also built several applications from source - and encountered some problems, which were resolved.  As for the home folder, it shows my correct original user in addition to the ones I was forced to create at boot.

Comment: Well done for solving your own problem! Would you mind editing your question to remove the solution and posting it as an answer in the answer section below? That would help future visitors find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching for why I was getting "not enough space", I stumbled on some suggestions for the 'force new user' issue:

1. Disable the gnome-initial-setup by commenting it out in
   `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop`.
   The line to comment was:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user
   ```

   That seemed to fix the issue, but intermittently.
2. Remove gnome-initial-setup package entirely

   ```
    sudo apt remove gnome-initial-setup
   ```
3. switch from gnome login to lightdm
4. Finally, the one that worked:

   ```
    a) edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
    b) Add/modify: 

        [daemon]
        InitialSetupEnable=False
   ```