# Ubuntu 20 undesired initial setup after each boot

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, users, restart

Context:

I upgraded from 18 to 20.04.

I have just one normal user A.

Expected behavior: on each system init, should open the window to login in user A.

Actual and Unexpected behavior: sometimes after system boots it forces an undesired initial setup to do a user creation. I think this happens on half of the boots.

If I restart the system during the undesired initial setup, it usually starts normally with the expected behavior so I can login normally in User A.

This issue starts after the upgrade.

SYSTEM specs:

System: Host: pedro-W54xEU Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Machine: Type: Laptop System: CLEVO product: W54xEU v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> Mobo: CLEVO model: W54xEU v: D02 serial: <superuser/root required>

BIOS: American Megatrends v: 4.6.5 date: 08/02/2013

CPU: Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium 2030M bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB Speed: 1214 MHz min/max: 1200/2500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1253 2: 1348

Graphics: Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 1366x768~60Hz, 1440x900~60Hz OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1) v: 4.2 Mesa 20.0.8

Audio: Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic

Network: Device-1: Realtek RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8723ae IF: wlan0 state: down mac: 48:d2:24:cf:e4:d0 Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:90:f5:ed:ed:19

Drives: Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 119.01 GiB (25.6%) ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB Partition: ID-1: / size: 154.09 GiB used: 119.01 GiB (77.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.88 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6

Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 63.0 C mobo: N/A Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A Info: Processes: 303 Uptime: 38m Memory: 11.58 GiB used: 3.89 GiB (33.6%) Shell: zsh inxi: 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

Disable the gnome-initial-setup by commenting it out in /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop.
The line to comment was:

`Exec=/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user`

I recommend to check this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277793/ubuntu-20-04-always-forces-me-to-create-a-new-user-at-boot)